# I am not able run C program in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I've been googling for about 2 days.  Read and followed a lot of instructions but nothing worked for me (including some instructions in this website; I know that people already asked this question in here).  I've downloaded Eclipse, installed the C/C++ plugin (window 7, 64 bit) but when I run the `HelloWorld.c` program, I get a pop-up message saying:

> Launch Failed. Binary Not Found.

Here is what I have done in Eclipse:

1. Window-->Preference-->New CDT Project Wizard-->Makefile Project-->Binary Parswer, make sure there is a checkmark infront of:  "PE Window Parser".
2. Project-->Properties-->C/C++ Build-->Settings-->Binary Parsers, make sure there is a checkmark infont of "PE Window Parser".
3. Project-->Properties-->C/C++ Build-->Tool Chain Editor:
   in the Current toolchain, select: Cross GCC
   in the Currect builder, Select: Gnu Make Builder.
4. set Eclipse CDT Auto Build

Here are steps I used to create the project:

1. File-->new-->C Project. enter "Hello" in the "Project name:" field. Click Next button, make sure both Debug and Release are checked, click Next button again, click Finish button.
2. Right click on Hello-->new-->Source File, enter HelloWorld.c, then click Finish button.
   enter the code below:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
   printf("Hello, world!\n");
   return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Save and click on the "Hammer" icon to build project.
   then I got this message:

> make all
>
> Cannot run program "make": Launching failed
>
> Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
>   PATH=[C:\eclipse_Juno;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
>
> 21:35:25 Build Finished (took 280ms)

1. Right click in the Text Editor area, Run As-->Local C/C++ Application
   a message pop up said: "Launch Failed.Binary not found"

I am not sure what I did wrong.  Please point out why I am not able to run my program in Eclipse.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution is in the error code - I think you don't have a C compiler installed. Do you? Example: VC/C++, MingW, GCC, Clang, etc.

Comment: You don't mention actually installing the actual program mentioned as missing here (`make`) nor any of the other compilers and tools. Did you? Did you follow the instructions in [this document?](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s03.jsp#wincompiler)

Comment: May be you want to look at the following link before going ahead.  http://www.ficksworkshop.com/blog/14-coding/69-setting-up-eclipse-cdt-on-windows

Comment: I'd just like to mention that documentation exists for a reason, and if you can't read and comprehend it, you shouldn't be a programmer...

Comment: @modifiablelvalue That's a little harsh. But it is also true.

Comment: @luserdroog The world is a little harsh. Let us presume a programmer is hired to work on a radiation therapy device. The job of the programmer is to update previously written software so that it'll run on newer hardware. The newer hardware introduces multiple processors to incorporate concurrency, but the programmer fails to notice this fact documented in the manual for the newer hardware. All of the sudden people are dying of radiation poisoning due to race conditions. This happened in real life... The harsh reality is that people *do die* as a result of negligence, ...

Comment: @luserdroog ... even when it's a basic programming error that was overlooked.

Comment: I don't know why you are saying like that.  The fact is I googled for two days and I did not see that link.  I did not know what else to do, that is why I asked in here.  Well, anyway, I followed that link above(http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s03.jsp#wincompiler) and it worked.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that no compiler was installed, and that eclipse is an integrated development environment which doesn't integrate a compiler natively.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem minutes ago. Do this:

Write your program, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello There\n");
    printf("salam");
}
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for `Build All`. You can do this from `Project -> Build All`.

Then, go to `Run -> Run Configuration` and on the left menu, double click on `C/C++ Application` (1), then click on the new opened option: "Sth Debug"(2). Now, on the main window, under `C/C++ Application:`, under the edittext, click `browse` option(3). Open your workspace, open your project, open `Debug` folder (which is created after each build), and select your a file with the same name as `ProjectFolderName`, then click `Run` (8).

**Important Note:**
Just select the file with the same name as `ProjectFolderName` without any suffix. Don't choose the files ending like: `sth.d` or `sth.o`. Just select file which has no suffix.

**Important Note2:**
You can put `${workspace_loc}/${project_name}/Debug/${project_name}` in the edittext too, but if you are using Windows, use backslashes() instead of slashes(/).

[image: Look at the picture]

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it simple for you in steps.

1. Go download MinGw or Cygwin in windows for eclipse.
2. Install any of them.
3. Go to Build Properties of the project and make your current compiler to point this installation directory.
4. Restart your Eclipse and try to build the program. Now, it should go fine with your running.

**Problem Explanation:**

- Binary not found: means you don't have .o file for your project to execute. This file will only get created after successful build of the project.
- Build Failed: is due to 'make' program is not available to Eclipse. That means, you don't have compiler with your eclipse to build the project.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: Thanks for formatting it. Will keep in mind to format the answer next time. :P